# How to check if point belongs to a triangle

Tags: coordinates

How can I check if a  coordinates (x,y) belong to a triangle with vertices coordinates v1, v2, v3?

How can I open both of them on the same figure to see the overlapping between the triangulation mesh with the image? in Matlab

Comment: Please post what language you are using and what code you've tried.

Comment: This question is not directly related to programming. Maybe our friends from Mathematics Stack Exchange will be able to help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/